# Can't import a utility jar class to dynamic web project

Tags: jakarta-ee, rad, ear, websphere-7

I am building an EAR called `myCommander`. I have a web module called `myCommanderWeb`.  I have a java module called `myConnect` which contains several `ldap` handler classes and a server api (third party software) handler class.  I'm using `RAD 7.5 with WAS 7.0` stub server.  I have added both modules to `myCommander`'s dependencies.  myConnect shows up as a Utility Jar in `myCommander`.  The only way I can use the handler classes in `myCommanderWeb` is to export `myConnect` as a jar and then add it to `myCommanderWeb`'s build path.  But this is retarding my testing processes.  If I make a change to myConnect, I have to re-jar it.  Then have to restart my WAS server. The reason I am breaking the myConnect out from myCommanderWeb is so I can use it for another web app (myOtherApp).

My questions are:

1. Am I missing something in the J2EE design that makes testing easier?
2. Is there a better way to structure my application?

I realize this is a slightly vague question set, but please respond with any direction possible.

Comment: what is your class loading policy? Parent_First /Last?

Comment: @MukulGoel I tried it both ways and get the class loading error. I made the class loading change at the server level. I'm testing by putting an import of a gimsConnect handler in a myCommanderWeb jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to test by adding myConnect's class folder to myCommanderWeb's build path. I added this line to myCommander's application.xml for deploying.

```
<library-directory>myConnect</library-directory>
```

Not sure if this is best practice, but it works well for what I'm trying to do.